# sbt 0.13.8 -- what is the difference between buildSettings and projectSettings?

Tags: scala, sbt

I am writing a new plugin for 0.13.8 and I can't seem to figure out the difference between the `buildSettings` Seq and the `projectSettings` Seq.

Can someone clarify?

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Plugins.html#projectSettings+and+buildSettings):

> With auto plugins, all provided settings (e.g. `assemblySettings`) are provided by the plugin directly via the `projectSettings` method.

And later on:

> If the plugin needs to append settings at the build-level (that is, in `ThisBuild`) there’s a `buildSettings` method. The settings returned here are guaranteed to be added to a given build scope only once regardless of how many projects for that build activate this AutoPlugin.
>
> The `globalSettings` is appended once to the global settings (in `Global`). These allow a plugin to automatically provide new functionality or new defaults. One main use of this feature is to globally add commands, such as for IDE plugins.
>
> Use globalSettings to define the default value of a setting.

Comment: Thanks. re-read the docs myslef and I think I get it better. Time for some experiments..